# How to debug the process linux in vmware boot up?

Tags: linux, debugging, boot

I'm proficient with debugging user space softwares by `gdb`,

but how can I use it to debug the process my linux vm boots up in vmware?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [these instructions](http://www.oslab.info/index.php/Misc/KGDB)?

Comment: So `gdb` can't do the job,must be `kgdb` instead?

Comment: That's my impression. The kernel is a very different beast than an a.out.

Answer (score -2):

Try attaching GDB to the VMware process.

Comment: Can you be more specific?I want to track down the bootstrap process of linux.